# rename files and remove shell PID as extention

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I am writing a script that checks  files in the directory has shell pid as an extension and rename them in such a way that extension is  removed. I have renamed couple of files to add ext using mv filename filename.$$.

I need advice on how to rename them again so that they do not contain the PID.

So far I have witten:

```
for file in *
do
if [ -s $file ]
then
  if [ $file = *.[0-9] ]
  then
  #mv command
  fi
fi
done
```

** this is harassing me for past couple of hours **

:(

Comment: Fix your formatting to make the code easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution can be:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch a.12345
touch b.23456

for file in *; do
  [[ $file =~ \.[0-9]+$ ]] && echo ${file%$BASH_REMATCH}
done
```

Output:

```
a
b
```

This will cut off the extension only if it contains only one or more numbers. Actually it also cut off the `.0000000000`, which is not a valid PID, but maybe this is not a big problem.

The `echo` command could be replaced by `mv "$file" "${file%$BASH_REMATCH}"`.

Comment: Thanks @TrueY. understood the regex bit, can you please explain me "echo ${file%$BASH_REMATCH}" mainly after file...

Comment: @BashNoob: The `[[ $VAR =~ RE ]]` matches $VAR against the regular expression on the right side. The matching part(s) placed to the `BASH_REMATCH` array. As I need only the first (and only) item from it, so no index needed to be added. The `${var%pattern}` removes the pattern from the end of the content of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

for i in *.+([[:digit:]]); do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

The trick is to use `extglob` (probably already turned on by default, by it doesn't hurt to turn it on again) so that `*.+([[:digit:]])` expands to all filenames that end with dot followed by one or more digits. Hence we don't need any regexps!

Comment: +1! I very rarely use extended glob, I think I should get more expreience with it! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the extensions of all files using:

```
for f in *.*
do 
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

As for your attempt, `[ .. ]` can't match against globs (and your glob would only match a single digit after the `.`). Use `[[ .. ]]` for that. You should also quote all occurrences of `$file`. Tools like shellcheck point these things out automatically.